# What is the process for reporting or assessing potentially dubious questions?

Tags: discussion, meta-faq

This is a meta question and personally, I think the answer should be on the footer of EVERY PAGE.

What is the process I ought to follow if I feel a question is of a dubious or unethical nature?

I did a few quick searches and found nothing obvious.  Considering the content of this family of web sites; it might be good to sometimes to nominate questions some vetting and perhaps ask for the use-case or application.

Like what if I asked, "how to programmatically coordinate multiple helicopter drones to converge on the New York Twin Towers in 1998?"

I'd like to imagine that kind of question gets bumped to some kind of "use case review" meta-management role to just ask the errant quester:

1. "Why did you ask?" or
2. "What will you use it for?"

I'm naive perhaps, not yet dumb.

Comment: Well, the example question would be closed as "too broad", and depending on the question's content, perhaps even "unclear". Do you have a more practical example though? We've had questions that smelled like "How do I programmatically spam the heck out of people" and those were downvoted pretty sigificantly.

Comment: If you asked that, it would be closed as "too broad" anyway. I think, on the premise of being professional Q/A site, we try not to ask the purpose of your question on a larger scale, since it can be related to company's intellectual property/user's stake on job/etc. Normally, we'll always try to assume in good faith. But if you think it smells *fishy*, you can flag the moderator. Edit: ninja'd

Answer (score 0):

If a post clearly has the purpose to do something illegal, you can flag it. There is a part about this in the [Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service), under the section "Restrictions".

> Any fraudulent, abusive, or otherwise illegal activity or any use of the Services or Content in violation of this Agreement may be grounds for termination of Subscriber’s right to Services or to access the Network.

Credit: I found this via [this answer](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/897/clarify-our-stance-on-black-hat-questions/928#928) on the IT Security Meta.